# How to make some values default vaslues and enable and other no default and disbale in an admin dialog which activate contact form fields

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app with an admin panel and one of the dialogs is for contact form fields.

Essentially in the contact form dialog there are switches which all by default are enable and those turn on the fields in the main app.

[image: Screenshot of the dialog contact form fields]

The screenshot shows the fields how are in the default way all turned on.

Right now the issue here is that the last field `preferredContactWay` should be off by default.

My solution to this problem was as follow but is a bad solution will be needed a more efficient one and less redundant code. A better solution is what I seek to my problem.

I created a second object called `availableContactFields` and removed from the original `defaultContactFields` preferredContactWay field.

```
const defaultContactFields = {
  name: {
    name: 'name',
    type: 'name',
  },
  email: {
    name: 'email',
    type: 'email',
    confirm: true,
  },
  phone: {
    name: 'phone',
    type: 'phone',
  },
  preferredContactHours: {
    name: 'preferredContactHours',
    type: 'select',
    options: ['8-20', '8-12', '12-16', '16-20'],
    defaultValue: '8-20',
  },
};

const availableContactFields = {
  name: {
    name: 'name',
    type: 'name',
  },
  email: {
    name: 'email',
    type: 'email',
    confirm: true,
  },
  phone: {
    name: 'phone',
    type: 'phone',
  },
  preferredContactHours: {
    name: 'preferredContactHours',
    type: 'select',
    options: ['8-20', '8-12', '12-16', '16-20'],
    defaultValue: '8-20',
  },
  preferredContactWay: {
    name: 'preferredContactWay',
    type: 'select',
    options: ['Phone call', 'SMS', 'Email'],
    defaultValue: 'Phone call',
  },
};
```

Then I have the next part function and I'm passing the default fields to have as default what should on and so the preferredContact way remains off initially

```
function EditContactFormDialog({ closeDialog, handleEdit, editItem }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);
  const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = useState(
    get(editItem, 'value') || Object.values(defaultContactFields),
  );

  console.log({ internalValue });

  function toggleEnabled(name, enabled) {
    console.log(name, enabled);
    const onlyEnabled = key =>
      (internalValue.some(val => val.name === key) && key !== name) ||
      (key === name && enabled);

    const toConfig = key =>
      internalValue.find(val => val.name === key) ||
      availableContactFields[key];

    setInternalValue(
      supported
        .map(itm => itm.name)
        .filter(onlyEnabled)
        .map(toConfig),
    );
  }

  function toggleConfirm(name, confirm) {
    setInternalValue(
      internalValue.map(val => (val.name === name ? { ...val, confirm } : val)),
    );
  }

  function toggleOptions(name, options) {
    setInternalValue(
      internalValue.map(val => (val.name === name ? { ...val, options } : val)),
    );
  }
```

the last part is the return of the component the map is taking this

```
const supported = [
  { name: 'name' },
  { name: 'email', confirmable: true },
  { name: 'phone', confirmable: true },
  { name: 'preferredContactHours' },
  { name: 'preferredContactWay' },
];
```

Then here the switches are rendered

```
return (
    <Dialog open>
      <DialogTitle className={classes.dialogTitle}>
        Customize contact form fields
      </DialogTitle>

      <DialogContent>
        <Table>
          <TableBody>
            {supported.map(({ name, confirmable }) => {
              const value = internalValue.find(item => item.name === name);
              console.log({ internalValue });
              const isEnabled = Boolean(value);
              console.log('boolean ->', { value }, ': ', { name }, ' : ', {
                isEnabled,
              });
              const isConfirm = isEnabled && value.confirm;
              const { options } = availableContactFields[name];
              const valueOptions = get(value, 'options', []);
              console.log(name, value);
              return (
                <TableRow key={name}>
                  <TableCell>
                    <FormControlLabel
                      control={
                        <Switch
                          color="primary"
                          checked={isEnabled}
                          onChange={({ target: { checked } }) =>
                            toggleEnabled(name, checked)
                          }
                        />
                      }
                      label={name}
                    />
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>
                    {confirmable && (
                      <FormControlLabel
                        disabled={!isEnabled}
                        control={
                          <Checkbox
                            checked={isConfirm}
                            onChange={({ target: { checked } }) =>
                              toggleConfirm(name, checked)
                            }
                          />
                        }
                        label="Confirm"
                      />
                    )}
                    {options && (
                      <FormControl
                        disabled={!isEnabled}
                        className={classes.fullWidth}
                      >
                        <InputLabel>Options</InputLabel>
                        <Select
                          multiple
                          value={valueOptions}
                          onChange={({ target }) =>
                            toggleOptions(name, target.value)
                          }
                          renderValue={selected => selected.join(', ')}
                        >
                          {options.map(option => (
                            <MenuItem key={option} value={option}>
                              <Checkbox
                                checked={valueOptions.includes(option)}
                              />
                              <ListItemText primary={option} />
                            </MenuItem>
                          ))}
                        </Select>
                      </FormControl>
                    )}
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              );
            })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </DialogContent>

      <DialogActions style={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
        <Button disabled={disabled} onClick={closeDialog}>
          Cancel
        </Button>

        <Button
          color="primary"
          variant="contained"
          disabled={disabled || internalValue.length < 1}
          onClick={() => {
            setDisabled(true);
            handleEdit(internalValue);
          }}
        >
          {disabled && <CircularProgress size={18} />}
          Save
        </Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question as I found a solution and could be ok at least doing the same as before.

To avoid having redundant code I added the following 2 lines inside the beginning of the component

```
  const availableContactFields = { ...defaultContactFields };
  delete availableContactFields.preferredContactWay;

  const [internalValue, setInternalValue] = useState(
    get(editItem, 'value') || Object.values(availableContactFields),
  );
```

In this way I'm deleting from the default fields the preferredContactWay and then the switch is kept off in default session.

Not sure is the right solution but at this moment work